# How can I take the name of a pipeline dynamically using the Email Sender snap in SnapLogic?

Tags: html-email, email, snaplogic

I want to take the name of a pipeline coming from the input stream directly so I can use the values to generate an HTML table in the Email Sender snap and write a report without having to generate a file first, so it can be more convenient.

My code looks something like this:

```
"<p>Hello,</p>" +

"<p><strong>Message</strong></p>"

+
"<table class=\"table table-striped\">
<thead class=\"thead-dark\">
  <tr>
    <th>Pipelines</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>" + $Pipeline + "</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>"
```

However, my issue with this is while it does take the values from the input stream, it repeats the first row based on how many input documents there are. If I were to have 5 input documents, I would get for example `Pipeline_1` repeated 5 times. The expression does not process the values after `Pipeline_1`.

I have tried using the `$("Pipeline:contains(Pipeline_1)");` method, however, this expression doesn't work and neither does the `match` expression.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share the expected input document and the desired output.

Comment: @BileshGanguly
My input consists of 

`Pipeline`
`State`
`Start_Time`
`Documents`

I load these dynamically using 
`<td>" + $Pipeline + "</td>
<td>" + $State+ "</td>
<td>" + $Start_Time+ "</td>
<td>" + $Documents+ "</td>`

However, only the first document is processed and is repeated as many times as there are entries.

Instead of getting `Pipeline_1` `Pipeline_2` `Pipeline_3`, I get:
`Pipeline_1` `Pipeline_1` `Pipeline_1`

Answer (score 0):

You can send incoming documents as an HTML table quite easily using the **Email Sender** snap.

*From SnapLogic Docs*

> For "HTML table" type, the Snap expects to find  and 
>   tags inside the Template body. One Document at the input view
>   corresponds to one row of the HTML table. For each Document, the Snap
>   gets a map data referenced by the Table-data path property and insert
>   a row into the HTML table of the message body. The Table-data path
>   property can also reference an array of map data. The Snap uses the
>   key sets of the map data to compose the column headers of the table.
>   The Snap processes the entire stream of Documents in a batch to
>   generate the superset of keys.

**Pipeline:**

Following is the test pipeline I made to demonstrate this.

[image: Test Pipeline]

**Input:**

Following is the Input JSON (created based on the description you provided) that I configured in the **JSON Generator** snap.

```
[
    {
        "Pipeline": "Pipeline_1",
        "State": "Completed",
        "Start_Time": "2019-12-18",
        "Documents": 1
    },
    {
        "Pipeline": "Pipeline_2",
        "State": "Completed",
        "Start_Time": "2019-12-17",
        "Documents": 200
    },
    {
        "Pipeline": "Pipeline_3",
        "State": "Completed",
        "Start_Time": "2019-12-18",
        "Documents": 10
    },
    {
        "Pipeline": "Pipeline_4",
        "State": "Failed",
        "Start_Time": "2019-12-16",
        "Documents": 25
    }
]
```

**Configuration:**

Following is an Email Template that I got from Snaplogic docs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
     <title>Email Snap HTML Table</title> 
<style type="text/css"> table.Snap {background-color:transparent;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;} table.Snap th, 
      table.Snap td {text-align:center;border:1px solid black;padding:5px;} table.Snap th {background-color:AntiqueWhite;} 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
        <p>Dear SnapLogic Users:</p> 
        <p>This is a sample Snap email with HTML Table email type.</p> 
        <table class="Snap"> 
        </table> 
        <p></p> 
        <p>Regards,</p> 
        <p>SnapLogic Staff</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Configuration required other than setting the template -

- **Email Type**: Set this as *HTML table*
- **Table-data path**: Set this to `$` which is the root element
- **Batch Size**: Set this to the number of rows you need to send in the email at a time

Following is a screenshot of the settings I used in the **Email Sender** snap.

[image: Email Sender settings]

> When using just `$` in the Table-data path, the Snap creates an HTML
>   table, wherein the Template Body has the HTML table tags
>   (`<table></table>`). Thus, the table auto-fills with the incoming
>   data.

*Note:* **The document structure needs to be flat.**

As far as the batch size is concerned -

> If the number of Documents the Snap receives from the input view
>   reaches the given Batch size, the Snap composes an email message with
>   an HTML table and sends it to the server. Multiple emails are
>   generated if needed to send out all Documents. The Snap sends the last
>   message at the end of the pipeline execution if any number of the
>   un-sent table rows remain.

**Result:**

Following is the screenshot of the mail I received.

[image: Email]

**References:**

- [SnapLogic Docs - Email Sender](https://docs-snaplogic.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/1438208/Email+Sender)